# Need to find an occurrence of a value in any beyond worksheet one and return the value of A:1 for each worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I need to search all worksheets for the values in Worksheet one column A.  The behavior should be similar to a CTRL-F find all selection.  In A:1 of every worksheet is a name and if the value from column A is in that worksheet then A:1 will be returned.  I do not need VLookup or HLookup.  It might be doable with index and search combo, but I am not finding a good way to do that.  I know I need an array search of some sort since I need to search everywhere.  I have a solution that does not scale and is sloppy on the return.  This is the formula I am currently using.

Column A is where the search values are pasted.  Columns B-Z or however far is needed get the formula pasted in the first 200 rows which is the limit of the allowed search terms.

```
{=IF(OR($A2<>""),IF(OR($A2=Sheet26!$A$1:SZ$25000),Sheet26!A$1,"Not Found"),"")}
```

That is the formula for column Z and the sheet numbers are changed for each column that has a sheet.  What I need to adjust this to is only having the formula in column B and it returning a concatenated value of all the names it found.  There are lots of questions dealing with just one value or one range like this [EXCEL: Need to find a value in a range of cells from another worksheet and return value from adjacent cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16308329/excel-need-to-find-a-value-in-a-range-of-cells-from-another-worksheet-and-retur) but nothing that actually answers what I need.

Currently the result I get is something like this.

```
A           B            C          D             E         ...
Star        Bob        Not Found     Ann          Not Found
Light       Bob         Jill          Not Found   Not Found
378         Not Found     Jill        Not Found   Not Found
```

What I would like to have is this

```
A          B         
Star       Bob, Ann
Light      Bob, Jill
378        Jill
```

How can I modify my formula to accomplish that?

Thanks

Comment: What version of Excel?

Comment: Not sure because it will be widely used on initially dozens of machines and could go district wide after that.  I think it is safe to say 2007 or greater.  There could be a couple of Mac versions running it as well, but at least with the existing formula that was not an issue.

Comment: That's too bad.  With 2016 it would be simple -- move your results column over by 1 (start in C2); change your formula to return `""` instead of `not found`, and use the `TEXTJOIN` function in Column B.  However, you could use a similar method with a UDF.  There are examples of `TEXTJOIN` vba functions on `SO` that will work with 2007+.

Comment: Of course, if you are going to use VBA, you could just use VBA for the entire project.

Comment: If I have to use VBA I will, or just a simple Python script to search through.  The problem is in the future it might not be me maintaining it so I am trying to keep it to a formula that I can leave easy directions to update.

Comment: If there is a column limit, then somewhere "off in the distance", you could set up a bunch of helper columns that concatenate the results of non-blank cells in that row one by one, and display the result back in column B (or a nested `IF` so long as the maximum number of columns isn't greater than the nesting limit for the oldest version of Excel you will be using.  Might be easier to explain a short VBA routine.

Comment: trying to clarify: you want to search all worksheets in one workbook for a keyword. ... the keyword is obtained from column A of a notToBeSearched worksheet. ... if the keyword is found on a worksheet, then the value in cell A1, of the worksheet where the keyword was found, is to be saved. ... after all the worksheets have been searched, all the saved values from the A1 cells are to be concatenated and returned to the caller of the function  .............. do i have it right?

Answer (score 1):

If you get tired of the formula approach, here is a VBA approach that should do what you describe.

- It looks at column 1 on sheet1 to get a list of words to search for
- read that list into a vba array (for speed)
- for each item in the list, search each worksheet to see if the item exists

  - I added each item to a Dictionary, and then concatenated the results with commas, but you could also construct a string on the fly, to store in the second "column" of the array
- After all is done, we write the results back to the worksheet.
- It should be able to handle any reasonable number of worksheets and search terms
- If necessary, you can limit the range to search on each worksheet; exclude certain worksheets from being searched; look at partial matches in a cell; select a case-sensitive search; etc.
- If there are blank entries between the first and last search terms, I have excluded the search.

---

```
Option Explicit
Sub FindAllColA()
    Dim WB As Workbook, WS As Worksheet
    Dim WS1 As Worksheet
    Dim D As Object
    Dim V
    Dim R As Range
    Dim FirstRow As Long, LastRow As Long
    Dim I As Long

Set D = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
Set WB = ThisWorkbook
Set WS1 = WB.Worksheets("Sheet1")

With WS1
    If .Cells(1, 1) <> "" Then
        FirstRow = 1
    Else
        FirstRow = .Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
    End If

    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'V will hold both search terms and the results
    V = .Range(.Cells(FirstRow, 1), .Cells(LastRow, 1)).Resize(columnsize:=2)
End With

For I = 1 To UBound(V)
    If Not V(I, 1) = "" Then
        D.RemoveAll
        For Each WS In WB.Worksheets
            If Not WS.Name = WS1.Name Then
            With WS
                If Not .Cells.Find(what:=V(I, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False) Is Nothing Then
                    D.Add .Cells(1, 1).Text, .Cells(1, 1).Text
                End If
            End With
            End If
        Next WS
        V(I, 2) = Join(D.Keys, ",")
    Else
        V(I, 2) = ""
    End If
Next I

With WS1
    Set R = .Range(.Cells(FirstRow, 1), .Cells(LastRow, 2))
    R.EntireColumn.Clear
    R = V
    R.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This is very similar to the Python I was thinking of using as well.  I will look into it and see if I think I can make it so a teacher with no development experience can modify it if needed.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another way, would be an UDF which can be used in a wider range without any changes like:

```
Public Function ValString(search_term As String, cell_string As Variant, ParamArray ignored_sheets()) As Variant

  Dim x As Variant

  If TypeOf cell_string Is Range Then cell_string = cell_string.Address

  If Not TypeOf Evaluate(cell_string) Is Range Then
    ValString = CVErr(2023)
    Exit Function
  ElseIf Range(cell_string).Cells.Count > 1 Then
    ValString = CVErr(2023)
    Exit Function
  End If

  If IsMissing(ignored_sheets) Then
    ignored_sheets = Array(Application.Caller.Parent.Name)
  Else
    For x = 0 To UBound(ignored_sheets)
      If TypeOf ignored_sheets(x) Is Range Then
        ignored_sheets(x) = ignored_sheets(x).Parent.Name
      ElseIf TypeName(ignored_sheets(x)) = "String" Or IsNumeric(ignored_sheets(x)) Then
        ignored_sheets(x) = Format(ignored_sheets(x), "@")
      Else
        ignored_sheets(x) = ""
      End If
    Next
  End If

  For Each x In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If IsError(Application.Match(x.Name, Array(ignored_sheets)(0), 0)) Then
      If Not x.Cells.Find(search_term, , -4163, 1, , , True) Is Nothing Then
        ValString = ValString & ", " & x.Range(cell_string).Value2
      End If
    End If
  Next

  If Len(ValString) Then
    ValString = Mid(ValString, 3)
  Else
    ValString = CVErr(2042)
  End If

End Function
```

Put the code in a Module and you can use it like a normal formula in your sheet.

Example:

```
=ValString(A1,"A1")
```

Or for your case:

```
=IFERROR(ValString(A1,"A1"),"Not Found")
```

Use: `ValString([search_term],[cell_string],{[ignored_sheet1],[ignored_sheet2],...})`

- `[search_term]:` the string to look for
- `[cell_string]:` the address of a cell as ref or string which you want to output if found
- `[ignored_sheets]:` *(optional)* the sheet names as strings or a ref to them you want to ignore

If `[ignored_sheets]` is omitted the sheet you have the formula in will be ignored. To include all sheets in the workbook simply set it to `""`
If nothing was found it will return `#N/A!` (which is good as you can catch this to set whatever output you want without changing the code)
If `[cell_string]` is not an address-string and/or goes for multiple cells, it will return `#REF!`
`[ignored_sheets]` is used as a list like `=ValString(A1,"A1",Sheet1!A1,Sheet5!A1)` or `=ValString(A1,"A1","Sheet3","Sheet4","Sheet7","MyWhateverSheetName")`. If used in the ref-way, you can rename the sheets and it will also in the formula. This is good if there is a summary sheet you do not want to check. But keep in mind: if used, the sheet with the formula itself, also needs to be included!

If you still have any questions, just ask ;)

Comment: the only real bad part about it is, that it need to be volatile to work in the expected way :(

Answer (score 0):

try this UDF

```
Function findKeywords(findMe As String) As String

    findKeywords = ""

    Dim sheetToSkip As String
    sheetToSkip = "Sheet1"

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

        If sht.Name <> sheetToSkip And Len(findMe) > 0 Then    ' do not look for blank cells

            ' note:    LookAt:=xlWhole ... whole word       LookAt:=xlPart ... partial

            Dim aaa As Range
            Set aaa = sht.Cells.Find( _
                            What:=findMe, _
                            After:=sht.Cells(1, 1), _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False, _
                            SearchFormat:=False)

            If Not aaa Is Nothing Then
                If Len(findKeywords) = 0 Then
                    findKeywords = sht.Range("a1")
                Else
                    findKeywords = findKeywords & ", " & sht.Range("a1")
                End If
            End If

        End If

    Next sht

'   If Len(findKeywords) = 0 Then findKeywords = "Not Found"     ' uncomment to return "Not Found" if desired
'   Debug.Print findKeywords


End Function
```